# Upgrade helm chart with new RoleBinding apiVersion only

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

My deployment job is failing with below error on test_cluter

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: current release manifest contains removed kubernetes api(s) for this kubernetes version and it is therefore unable to build the kubernetes objects for performing the diff. error from kubernetes: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "RoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

test_cluster -> apiVersion=**rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1**,

dev_cluster -> apiVersion=**rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1** (Where deployment is successful)

Now, making local changes in manifest file is not helping here. Failing with same error. How do I update/upgrade already deployed helm charts?
Could someone help me understand the issue and point to remedy ?

TIA!

Comment: i guees that you use `v1.22+` k8s  version where `v1beta1` was  replaced with `v1` for 
[release notes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/07/14/upcoming-changes-in-kubernetes-1-22/).


Just edit `v1beta1` with `v1`  for `RoleBinding` resource

Answer (score 0):

As @MikhailZnak suggested.

v1beta1 was replaced with v1 for [release notes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/07/14/upcoming-changes-in-kubernetes-1-22/). Just edit v1beta1 with v1 for RoleBinding resource